# Unable to call module output on product listing

Tags: module, magento-1

I have a custom delivery-date module (Magento 1.9) which outputs the delivery date based on all kinds of variables. The setup is pretty easy, and I can display the delivery date on the product page;

In default.xml in my theme

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="MyModule_catalog/deliverydate" name="delivery_date" template="catalog/product/view/delivery_date.phtml"/>
```

then in the view.phtml I call it like so;

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('delivery_date')); ?>
```

And this works great. Now I want to show this delivery date on the product list/category view as well. So I tried to add the xml block from the `catalog_product_view` to the `catalog_category_default` and `catalog_category_view` using the same PHP code to echo the date; but nothing shows.

I have a feeling I'm missing something, but I can't see what. The modules class `class MyModule_Catalog_Block_Deliverydate extends Mage_Core_Block_Template` extends the Core_Block_Template; so it should be available everywhere.
In the modules config.xml it says;

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <mymodule_catalog>
            <class>MyModule_Catalog_Block</class>
        </mymodule_catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

So as far as my (limited) knowledge about this reaches, it should just be available to call on the product-listing as well, right? Why doesn't it?

Edit: 
These are the relevant parts of my default.xml

```
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="mymodule_catalog/stock" name="stock_text" template="catalog/product/view/stock.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <block type="mymodule_catalog/stock" name="stock_text" template="catalog/product/view/stock.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <block type="mymodule_catalog/stock" name="stock_text" template="catalog/product/view/stock.phtml"/>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <block type="mymodule_catalog/stock" name="stock_text" template="catalog/product/view/stock.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_view>
```

Edit2: Contents of the view/delivery_date.phtml (really simple)

```
<?php echo $this->getDeliverydate(); ?>
```

Comment: Please share `catalog_category_default and catalog_category_view` xml code

Comment: @kunj I updated my question! :)

Comment: @AlexTimmer , Also add the code of "catalog/product/view/delivery_date.phtml" in question. So i can see there is product condition there or not.

Comment: I hope you used `MyModule_catalog/deliverydate` correctly in product page. if it is working on product page so it should be same on category page `MyModule_catalog/stock`

Comment: @ChiragRajput done! Tho the phtml is really nondescript; it's just an echo.

Comment: @AlexTimmer , Then its calling function from block file name - "deliverydate.php". There you have get idea about code

Comment: @ChiragRajput; I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: You need to have a look in code (function ) in block file. You can do print something and do exit in code. So you can debug it in this way.

Comment: The problem isn't in the function; they work fine on the product view. I do find that view/delivery_date.phtml isn't called at all...